# TypeError: get() expected a dict or protobuf message, got <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

Tags: python, opencv, ocr, google-vision

I'm trying to take a region of a picture using OpenCV, and then extracting that text. Any idea how to fix this error?

```
roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.imshow('image2', roi)
cv2.waitKey(0)

response = client.text_detection(image=roi)
texts = response.text_annotations
string = texts[0].description

print(string)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[text_detection](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.ImageAnnotatorClient.text_detection) method expects an Cloud Vision [Image](https://googleapis.dev/python/vision/latest/gapic/v1/types.html#google.cloud.vision_v1.types.Image) task instance for analization, where you're passing [Image](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-opencv-cv2-cvtcolor-method/) instance of another type.

You can convert OpenCV image instance to the one suitable for google-vision client methods:

```
roi = cv2.cvtColor(roi, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
success, encoded_image = cv2.imencode('.jpg', roi)
roi_image = encoded_image.tobytes()
roi_image = vision.types.Image(content=roi_image)
response = client.text_detection(image=roi_image)
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Except for some reason, even if I import types, i have to replace all vision.types with vision_v1 to make it work. Just FYI for anyone that later has a problem.